# Store create not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model-associations

I am trying to create a form that will allow my users to create a store that is associated with them in rails.

I have a has_many and belongs_to association in place but can't seem to get the store to even save to the database to see if the association is working.

Currently for the form in my stores#new view I have:

```
<%= form_for @store do |f| %>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

and for my new and create actions I have the following in my stores controller

```
def new
  @store = Store.new
end

def create
  @user = current_user 
  @store = @user.stores.new(params[:stores])

  if @store.save
    redirect_to store_path
  else
    render newstore_path
  end
end
```

My model name is definitely singular as well (store).

This has worked for me in the past and so I am confused why it isn't now.

If someone could show me the absolute easiest way to successfully associate two models using nested resources and then create a form that will maintain this association that would be unbelievably helpful as I have been struggling with this for the past few days and really think a solid example would help.

Any information people can offer would be excellent though. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a form for nested resources, you'll probably need

```
<%= form_for [@user, @store] do |f| %>
```

You might also want to try using create or build in the create action of your controller, as opposed to new.

There's also a good Railscast on forms for nested models:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any nested attributes here. you are in the Store controller and i assume the store#new view too. So you are just creating a store with the user_id field as current_user.id or `current_user.stores.build(params[:stores])` should be working in your create method.

Let's see your view first too, and what does console say when you do `u = User.first; u.stores.create!`

Lastly, imo, this is just a User has many stores association, no need for a habtm.

Comment: Hey Pjammer, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I still can't get it to actually save into the database. It doesn't throw up any errors at all, just doesn't save into my stores table - do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: When you use the bang method `create!` it saves into the db or errors.  Usually those are the only two options. if you can paste the console of you creating a `User.first.stores.create!` it's not that i don't believe you but...

Comment: Hey Pjammer, I just gave your idea of `User.first.stores.create!` and it happily added a store line to the stores table including user_id. I then try the same thing in my view though `current_user.stores.create!(params[:stores])` and it doesn't work - is it the params element that is wrong? thanks again for your help :)

Comment: So, in your log you should have why it didn't save now. It may be hidden in the mess of the last call to the server, but it should be there. look for it. Using `binding.pry` from the pry gem in your create method and you can see what params are being passed.